# ASP.NET Web App, create subdomains dynamically

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms, subdomain

I have a web app and I'd like to create subdomains for every new user. The users fill out the form, pay online and the system creates a new subdomain for those users in seconds, this has to work Like all CRM companies (for example 37signals.com)

I'd like the best approach for this situation regarding web app and database. The app is an ASP.NET web app and mySql database.

1. How can I create a new subdomain dynamically for each user?
2. Do I vave to create a new database for each user or I use the same one for all of them?
3. If I use the same database, depending on the number of users the database could be too big...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On StackOverflow, we prefer there be only one question per question. Split this into two questions: one for point #1, and one for points #2-3. Also, specify whether you are planning on using WebForms or MVC, because that makes a difference in how you tackle #1.

Comment: Web Forms sorry. The important question is number 1, but 2-3 are related to what you decide on #1. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On point 1, you can give the illusion of creating a 'subdomain' for each user by using Routing: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx